# One Common database of sqlserevr for web And desktop

Tags: c#, sql-server

I have a school Management system and school have more branches  they say we should have one common db 
and i think  i will host my db but i dont know who i can make a connection wirh desktop application and online database

Comment: exactly like you do a local one - just put the right server name in - and be sure if theres a firewall the port is open

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it's a terrible idea exposing your database to the internet. Much better solution would be to write a Web API that is exposed to the internet which both the web and desktop apps use to perform their tasks by interacting with the API.

Comment: The database can stay in intranet, and is _web api_ related to question about __common database__?